# Send ajax header in Pythin

Tags: python, ajax

One website API require pass as an ajax header to order to setup the connection

```
.$.ajaxSetup(
{
    headers:
    {
        'API-Key': "<your api key>"
    }
});
```

I write a Python to simulate this connection,but could only get a response 200:

```
import sys, socket
import requests

url= 'http://demo.datagearbox.com/api'
access_token ='543d927eecf39069b31cceee60e9d6d1'

result = requests.post(url,
      headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
               'Authorization': 'API-Key {}'.format(access_token)})

print(result)
```

Can someone please tell me what I missed?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = requests.post(url,
      headers={
          'Content-Type':'application/json', 
          'API-Key': '{}'.format(access_token)
      }
)
```

Comment: still response [200]

Comment: Were you expecting "401 Unauthorized" or something? Try changing the access_code to something not valid such as "12345" and see what happen. Like SuperStew said, 200 mean you've supplied the correct code and thing are working properly